# Automounting USB-UART/FIFO IC (as ttyUSB0) with 0666 permissions - udev

Tags: permissions, usb, centos7, udev, automount

I'm trying to automount the following device with 0666 permissions:

```
lsusb -vvv

Bus 001 Device 094: ID 0403:6014 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232H Single HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0403 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
  idProduct          0x6014 FT232H Single HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
  bcdDevice            9.00
  iManufacturer           1 FTDI
  iProduct                2 C232HM-DDHSL-0
  iSerial                 3 FTVWEM02
  bNumConfigurations      1
```

To achieve this I created the following udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6014", MODE="0666", RUN+="/usr/bin/touch /tmp/udev-test.txt"code here
```

As you can see I verify the functionality of the rule with a test file. The file is always created on the connection of the USB device.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     0 Oct 20 09:56 udev-test.txt
```

That should mean that the rule is functioning... however it never gets the permissions right.

When running `ls -l /dev/ttyU*` I get the following result:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Oct 20 09:56 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Strangely enough if I run chmod from the command line as root, I can always change the permissions of the device. I would like that to happen on every plug-in automatically. Could you please help me?

**I'm running Scientific Linux 7**

```
Linux version 4.7.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 (mockbuild@Build64R7) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sat Sep 24 11:54:29 EDT 2016
```

**The topics I already searched through:**

- [Udev rule is not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466059/udev-rule-is-not-being-applied) - solution not working
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116854/udev-created-my-symblic-link-to-my-device-but-permission-not-set
- [Change ttyUSB permissions using udev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291431/change-ttyusb-permissions-using-udev) - if I add KERNEL=="ttyUSB*" or KERNEL=="ttyUSB0" the rule is not working anymore
- [Run script with udev after USB plugged in on RPi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295198/run-script-with-udev-after-usb-plugged-in-on-rpi)